# Does Spring Cloud support a discovery client that uses both the userid and service name?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

In the tutorial [microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka) a REST request is made the `bookmark-service` like this:

```
    // use the "smart" Eureka-aware RestTemplate
    ResponseEntity<List<Bookmark>> exchange =
            this.restTemplate.exchange(
                    "http://bookmark-service/{userId}/bookmarks",
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    null,
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Bookmark>>() {
                    },
                    (Object) "mstine");

    exchange.getBody().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Suppose half the `userid` instances are on one server and the other half are on another server.  Does the DiscoveryClient support figuring out which `bookmark-service` server to query for the provided `userid`?

Comment: One solution would be to add the user IDs supported by a given instance to the metadata published to the Eureka server.  See https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Overriding-Default-Configurations.  You would then need to add some logic to you Ribbon client in the example above to select the correct instance based on that metadata,  The other solution would be to add some kind of LB infront of the instances that knows how to wrote the request.

Comment: Thanks good tip - I'm reading up on it right now.  I think that if I can get the meta data (userIDs) into the eureka server and update the discovery client so that it queries Eureka by serviceName and userID then the rest should be easy ... famous last words :).